# Check executable is on a specific path in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to try and check an executable (in this case Python's `pip`) is on a specific path (the virtual environment) in the Makefile (this will be done prior to running a `make` command to install all the requirements, and is a safety measure to ensure they don't end up in system python by mistake).

(Also, yes, I know I can force a virtual env for pip, but this isn't just for me, so I can't guarantee that's done ...)

I've had a few attempts, but currently have this:

```
DIRENV := $(shell pwd)/.direnv/
PIP    := $(shell which pip)

.PHONY: check-pip
check-pip: 
    FOUND_PIP := $(if $(findstring $(PIP),$(DIRENV)),found,)
    $(info FOUND_PIP=$(FOUND_PIP))
    ifeq ($(FOUND_PIP),found)
        $(info Found pip on the path)
    else
        $(error ERROR: Cannot find pip))
    endif
```

`$(DIRENV)` and `$(PIP)` are correct if I print them out.

There are 2 issues with this:

1. I can't seem to get `findstring` to work at all!
2. The `ifeq` runs both parts of the conditional regardless.

```
❯ make check-pip
FOUND_PIP=
Found pip on the path
Makefile:37: *** ERROR: Cannot find pip.  Stop.
```

And just to clarify the `make` version:

```
❯ make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
```

Comment: Here's the thing you have to understand: a _recipe_ in a makefile (the thing after the target/prerequisites, that is indented by TAB) is a _shell script_.  So when you write recipes, you have to use _shell_ syntax, not _makefile_ syntax.

Comment: Each line in a makefile recipe is executed in a separate shell. Can't use variables like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your check recipe using *shell* syntax.

```
.PHONY: check-pip
check-pip:
         case "$(PIP)" in \
           ("$(DIRENV)"/*) echo "Found pip on the path" ;; \
           (*) echo "Cannot find pip"; exit 1 ;; \
         esac
```

Note, you need this if you only want to check this when the user specifically runs the `check-pip` target.

If you want to check it always whenever the user runs `make` regardless of which target they specify, then you can use makefile operations but you should not put them in a recipe, because they are run as the makefile is parsed not when a target is built.  And you don't need a `check-pip` target at all.

Comment: What if I put it as a dependency on a couple of other targets?

Comment: You can do that.  I'm not sure I understand the question...?

Comment: I mean if I have a couple of recipes to install / clean and reinstall the environment and I want this check to pass before they do anything.

Comment: BTW, this works, thanks! Though the quotes around `$(DIRENV)*` need removing or it's matching the wrong string.

Comment: Sorry the quotes should have just been around the variable not the glob character.  Fixed.